# Netsuite closing sales order doesn't trigger user event scripts

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript2.0

It doesn't seem like closing sales orders through the Netsuite button triggers User event scripts.

I'm trying to prevent sales orders from being closed if a certain field is not populated. I can check if all line items are closed before closing the sales order but the beforesubmit function is not triggering specifically for closing sales orders. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Do you mean the "Close All Remaining Lines" button?

Comment: Yes, although it only says Close Order on the sales order record

Answer (score 2):

That's "correct" - or at least "working as intended"; many of the native buttons other than `Save` don't trigger any customizations. It's incredibly frustrating. I've seen quite a few solutions in the past that essentially added a custom Close button that would trigger their custom close logic.

Comment: I got it to work by essentially doing what you said. I hid the close order button from the sales order, created a new button via user event script and attached functionality to it via jQuery injection on a client script.

Comment: @PyroAddict I know it's been quite time since you implemented it. Can you please share the code you implemented?